# Passing by reference to shuffle() does not work / built-in functions joining in PHP

Tags: php

An aspect of PHP:

```
$numbers = shuffle(range(11, 20));
```

This will not work. It produeces a "Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference", so it should be formulated like this:

```
$numbers = range(11, 20); 
shuffle($numbers);
```

As far as I've been working with PHP there are built-in functions that I would be able to connect (with each other).

a) Are there any general rules related to this and is there a way I could find and explanation on the Net?

b) How would you estimate the percentage of the functions that are connectible and the ones that are not?

c) Could there be any other aspects like nesting deeper and this would not work (like chaining 10 separate functions would not work but they would work in pairs)?

Thanks.

Comment: As related to this particular example - "The reasoning is that the Fisher-Yates sorting algorithm operates in-place, so accepting by-reference is more efficient, as it avoids a copy of the array."

Comment: shuffle() returns true when succesfull, not the product of its opperation! http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Another insight related to this - "the function modifies the argument, so you have to give them a variable that can be modified. A function return can not be modified (where would the modified value go)?"

Comment: Thanks VA79 - this makes sense. This is the answer that I was looking for as it explains this fact. So basically I could look as what particular function returns and then determine whether it will be connectible with other functions based on that ("in general"). I mean, can this be determined based on some things, lets say in the manual on php.net?

Comment: I dont think there is a "something" to check this with except the return values themselfs

Comment: I am learning the PHP and I am kind of going deeper on things. The "bool(true)" could be assigned to $numbers with this, but it is not. I am kind of looking for some general rules, so I could learn, but it seems like something that I should not be worrying about at this point. I guess some will work together, some will not, and I will figure this out over time. Thanks again!

Comment: It really is a mather of getting to know the different functions like you say. Some functions like shuffle an sort just dont return what you expact, but knowing that you can always create your own funtions. :)